# Aptana syntax highlight issue - JavaScript

Tags: syntax-highlighting, aptana3

After the last update of Aptana it stopped to syntax highlight all of my JavaScript code. I tried to fix this for a couple of days with reinstalling the editor, using Eclipse and install Aptana as a plugin and also tweak different settings.

[image: Aptana code highligtning]

As you can see on the image all the code after line 224 turns white. And I have not found any specific code combination that seem to trigger this bug.

Worth mention is that some of the code starts to highlight again when you change something in the line and sometimes Aptana still highlights the code further down in the document.

I would really appreciate if someone has a solution on this issue.

my best ~ Pontus

Comment: i got the exact same problem since I updated to the newest version

Answer (score 2):

had the same issue. it turned out that there was a "wrong" whitespace character. if you activate the option "show whitespace characters" you can differ between regular "space" characters (marked by a dot in middle of line) and other whitespace characters.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bMsg.png --> "wrong" whitespace character in condition (after the "||")